# microSDXC Card not responding to SD Interface commands in 3.3V mode

Tags: fpga, sd

I want to interface a 64GB microSDXC Card via 50MHz SD Bus mode (not UHS, 400kHz during initialization).
My initialization sequence works fine with the regular 2 GB SD card from my phone up to ACMD41, which is not supported by this card (card responds on CMD_IN while CMD_T is high):
[image: Card response]

Yet, with the 64GB SDXC, there is no card response at all:
[image: no response]

The card is powered and clocked for several seconds before the initialization sequence. It works when I put it into my workstation. CardSelect(DAT3 line) is asserted high during CMD0.

Am I missing something in the specification? What could I be doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the input :).

Answer (score 1):

I have recently made a SD/MMC interface (for a FPGA). IMHO, the standard do not make much sense.

Anyway :

- My init sequence starts with CMD0 / CMD8 / ACMD41 (repeated) / CMD2 / CMD3...
- You may need to send ACMD41 several times.
- In normal mode, the card changes outputs on falling edges, in high speed mode (up to 50MHZ), the card changes outputs on rising clock edges.

Hope this helps...

(I have tried SD, SDHC, MicroSDHC and MMCmobile cards, but no MicroSDXC.)